# Need to add one more text field in database table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-insert-id

I am using UserCake code for User Management solution.
I need to add one more new field as a "mobile1" in database.

So i have added new column as a "mobile1" in user table. And included text field 
in register.php file.

```
<?php
/*
UserCake Version: 2.0.2
http://usercake.com
*/


class User 
{
    public $user_active = 0;
    private $clean_email;
    public $status = false;
    private $clean_password;
    private $username;
    private $mobile1;
    private $displayname;
    public $sql_failure = false;
    public $mail_failure = false;
    public $email_taken = false;
    public $username_taken = false;
    public $displayname_taken = false;
    public $activation_token = 0;
    public $success = NULL;

    function __construct($user,$display,$pass,$email,$mobile1)
    {
        //Used for display only
        $this->displayname = $display;

        //Sanitize
        $this->clean_email = sanitize($email);
        $this->clean_password = trim($pass);
        $this->username = sanitize($user);
        $this->mobile1 = sanitize($mobile1);

        if(usernameExists($this->username))
        {
            $this->username_taken = true;
        }
        else if(displayNameExists($this->displayname))
        {
            $this->displayname_taken = true;
        }
        else if(emailExists($this->clean_email))
        {
            $this->email_taken = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //No problems have been found.
            $this->status = true;
        }
    }

    public function userCakeAddUser()
    {
        global $mysqli,$emailActivation,$websiteUrl,$db_table_prefix;

        //Prevent this function being called if there were construction errors
        if($this->status)
        {
            //Construct a secure hash for the plain text password
            $secure_pass = generateHash($this->clean_password);

            //Construct a unique activation token
            $this->activation_token = generateActivationToken();

            //Do we need to send out an activation email?
            if($emailActivation == "true")
            {
                //User must activate their account first
                $this->user_active = 0;

                $mail = new userCakeMail();

                //Build the activation message
                $activation_message = lang("ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_MESSAGE",array($websiteUrl,$this->activation_token));

                //Define more if you want to build larger structures
                $hooks = array(
                    "searchStrs" => array("#ACTIVATION-MESSAGE","#ACTIVATION-KEY","#USERNAME#"),
                    "subjectStrs" => array($activation_message,$this->activation_token,$this->displayname)
                    );

                /* Build the template - Optional, you can just use the sendMail function 
                Instead to pass a message. */

                if(!$mail->newTemplateMsg("new-registration.txt",$hooks))
                {
                    $this->mail_failure = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Send the mail. Specify users email here and subject. 
                    //SendMail can have a third parementer for message if you do not wish to build a template.

                    if(!$mail->sendMail($this->clean_email,"New User"))
                    {
                        $this->mail_failure = true;
                    }
                }
                $this->success = lang("ACCOUNT_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE_TYPE2");
            }
            else
            {
                //Instant account activation
                $this->user_active = 1;
                $this->success = lang("ACCOUNT_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE_TYPE1");
            }   



            if(!$this->mail_failure)
            {


                //Insert the user into the database providing no errors have been found.
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$db_table_prefix."users (
                    user_name,
                    display_name,
                    password,
                    email,
                    mobile1,
                    activation_token,
                    last_activation_request,
                    lost_password_request, 
                    active,
                    title,
                    sign_up_stamp,
                    last_sign_in_stamp
                    )
                    VALUES (
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    '".time()."',
                    '0',
                    ?,
                    'New Member',
                    '".time()."',
                    '0'
                    )");

                $stmt->bind_param("sssssi", $this->username, $this->displayname, $secure_pass, $this->clean_email, $this->mobile1, $this->activation_token, $this->user_active);
                $stmt->execute();
                $inserted_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
                $stmt->close();

                //Insert default permission into matches table
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$db_table_prefix."user_permission_matches  (
                    user_id,
                    permission_id
                    )
                    VALUES (
                    ?,
                    '1'
                    )");
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $inserted_id);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();

            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

The Data not inserting in Mysql.....
Please help
Appreciate your support.
Thanks

Comment: Which insert statement does not work? What are the values that will be inserted?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you should always encapsulate column names in case it is reserved:

```
//Insert the user into the database providing no errors have been found.
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$db_table_prefix."users (
    `user_name`,
    `display_name`,
    `password`,
    `email`,
    `mobile1`,
    `activation_token`,
    `last_activation_request`,
    `lost_password_request`, 
    `active`,
    `title`,
    `sign_up_stamp`,
    `last_sign_in_stamp`
    )
    VALUES (
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    '".time()."',
    '0',
    ?,
    'New Member',
    '".time()."',
    '0'
    )") or die($mysqli->error);
```

Comment: Do you see any error? or if page is completely blank check apache/mysql/php logs for errors.

Comment: While using backticks is a good practice, none of these column names seem to be reserved keywords.

Comment: That's correct Konstantin, but consistency is key when working with multiple developers so call it force of habit. My interest was more towards the `or die()`

Comment: @Zanderwar
I didn't seen any error.
If i removed mobile1 field means values are storing perfectly.

Comment: Just for a bit of trial and error, add `echo 'hello';` to line 115 after `if(!$this->mail_failure) {` then try again, just to make sure you're in the right place.

Comment: Hey @Zanderwar
I tried printing hello. It doesn't work with the full code.
The same way i just removed all code and print just hello. It prints....

Comment: Your problem is not with the SQL syntax. The script either fails before it reaches `if(!$this->mail_failure) {` or `$this->mail_failure` has the value of `true`. You may have to look in $mail class to see if it is validating form data in anyway also.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. Here is the updated code  .

```
<?php
    /*
    UserCake Version: 2.0.2
    http://usercake.com
    */


    class User 
    {
        public $user_active = 0;
        private $clean_email;
        public $status = false;
        private $clean_password;
        private $username;
        private $displayname;
        public $sql_failure = false;
        public $mail_failure = false;
        public $email_taken = false;
        public $username_taken = false;
        public $displayname_taken = false;
        public $activation_token = 0;
        public $success = NULL;
        private $mobile1;

        function __construct($user,$display,$pass,$email,$mobile1)
        {
            //Used for display only
            $this->displayname = $display;

            //Sanitize
            $this->clean_email = sanitize($email);
            $this->clean_password = trim($pass);
            $this->username = sanitize($user);
            $this->mobile1 = sanitize($mobile1);

            if(usernameExists($this->username))
            {
                $this->username_taken = true;
            }
            else if(displayNameExists($this->displayname))
            {
                $this->displayname_taken = true;
            }
            else if(emailExists($this->clean_email))
            {
                $this->email_taken = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //No problems have been found.
                $this->status = true;
            }
        }

        public function userCakeAddUser()
        {
            global $mysqli,$emailActivation,$websiteUrl,$db_table_prefix;

            //Prevent this function being called if there were construction errors
            if($this->status)
            {
                //Construct a secure hash for the plain text password
                $secure_pass = generateHash($this->clean_password);

                //Construct a unique activation token
                $this->activation_token = generateActivationToken();

                //Do we need to send out an activation email?
                if($emailActivation == "true")
                {
                    //User must activate their account first
                    $this->user_active = 0;

                    $mail = new userCakeMail();

                    //Build the activation message
                    $activation_message = lang("ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_MESSAGE",array($websiteUrl,$this->activation_token));

                    //Define more if you want to build larger structures
                    $hooks = array(
                        "searchStrs" => array("#ACTIVATION-MESSAGE","#ACTIVATION-KEY","#USERNAME#"),
                        "subjectStrs" => array($activation_message,$this->activation_token,$this->displayname)
                        );

                    /* Build the template - Optional, you can just use the sendMail function 
                    Instead to pass a message. */

                    if(!$mail->newTemplateMsg("new-registration.txt",$hooks))
                    {
                        $this->mail_failure = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Send the mail. Specify users email here and subject. 
                        //SendMail can have a third parementer for message if you do not wish to build a template.

                        if(!$mail->sendMail($this->clean_email,"New User"))
                        {
                            $this->mail_failure = true;
                        }
                    }
                    $this->success = lang("ACCOUNT_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE_TYPE2");
                }
                else
                {
                    //Instant account activation
                    $this->user_active = 1;
                    $this->success = lang("ACCOUNT_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE_TYPE1");
                }   



                if(!$this->mail_failure)
                {

                    //Insert the user into the database providing no errors have been found.
                    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$db_table_prefix."users (
                        user_name,
                        display_name,
                        password,
                        email,
                        activation_token,
                        last_activation_request,
                        lost_password_request, 
                        active,
                        title,
                        sign_up_stamp,
                        last_sign_in_stamp,
                        mobile1
                        )
                        VALUES (
                        ?,
                        ?,
                        ?,
                        ?,
                        ?,
                        '".time()."',
                        '0',
                        ?,
                        'New Member',
                        '".time()."',
                        '0',
                        ?

                        )");

                    $stmt->bind_param("sssssii", $this->username, $this->displayname, $secure_pass, $this->clean_email, $this->activation_token, $this->user_active, $this->mobile1);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $inserted_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
                    $stmt->close();

                    //Insert default permission into matches table
                    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$db_table_prefix."user_permission_matches  (
                        user_id,
                        permission_id
                        )
                        VALUES (
                        ?,
                        '1'
                        )");
                    $stmt->bind_param("s", $inserted_id);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
```